# How to get file (image) path location and insert it into SQL Statements to MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

Im trying to insert an image in my MSSQL database and render an image based on the path that is selected by user using variable "strpath". I dont know if it is possible but Im still getting an error on this. Anyone can help?

```
Private Sub Cmdbutton_selectimage_Click()

Dim strpath As String
Dim cou As Integer

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
cou = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If cou <> 0 Then
    strpath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strpath)
    Image1.PictureSizeMode = 1


End If
End Sub


Function GetInsertImage() As String

Dim SQLStrImage As String

SQLStrImage = _
    "INSERT INTO PeopleImage(Image)" & _
    " SELECT BulkColumn" & _
    " FROM Openrowset(Bulk '" & strpath & "', Single_Blob) as image"

GetInsertImage = SQLStrImage

End Function
```

I tried inserting and manually define the path location for e.g 'C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\images.png' and it works perfectly (inserted into table PeopleImage as binary) - This works perfectly

```
Function GetInsertImage() As String

Dim SQLStrImage As String

SQLStrImage = _
    "INSERT INTO PeopleImage(Image)" & _
    " SELECT BulkColumn" & _
    " FROM Openrowset(Bulk 'C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\images.png', Single_Blob) as image"

GetInsertImage = SQLStrImage

End Function
```

Comment: don't store images in database. Just store the path to the location on webserver

Comment: what is the drawback? and what are your suggestions? and do I just manually insert a string of the image path to the database as the SQL insert statement?

Comment: How do you connect with SQL server in VBA? Adodb?
Either way, you might want to have a look at [this topic](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/119950.aspx)
 over at vbcity.com

Comment: yes New ADODB.Connection

Comment: save the file location i.e insert the file name or path in db and Retrieving an image from a database incurs significant overhead compared to using the file system , so it is a bad idea to do it.

Comment: @Sameer if the images are stored locally and they need to be retrieved elsewhere, I can image the "why" behind wanting to do this. Other than that you're right - from a performance perspective it's never a good idea to store the images themselves in the db.

Comment: @RikSportel elsewhere meaning inside the network so storing them on webserver will do the trick

Comment: Thanks @RikSportel and Sameer, thanks for the explanation, however anyone of you have any idea whats the mistake on my code?  I'm trying this alternative to store image as BLOB cos i just need storing on few images.

Comment: @AdhikaLim share the error that you are getting